# EDS analysing the elemental composition

Tags: spectroscopy

Just wondering if I'm interpreting this correctly. So in SEM, and particularly the EDS mode, the beam irradiation refers to the beam irradiation from the thermionic emission gun. This paper measures the EDS spectra with varying degrees of irradiation in a 2D structure of BiOCl, noting that the structure of the compound changes under high beam irradiation to disintegrated domains of bismuth nanoparticles. I'm wondering is this a problem that is often encountered in EDS when trying to analyse the elemental composition of a sample in many other compounds?
Many Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of course the electron beam tears up the bonding on the surface. The SEM is like a 50 cal machine gun shooting at a brick wall.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm just reading about SEM for first time today, so I don't know much about it. Would it have a big effect on most sample materials, and would the primary reason choosing a shorter live time be that a change in composition occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying ask. Let me add that a SEM operates in a high vacuum, and the sample must be coated with a conducting film. So an actual loss of material from the surface (and SEM EDS is a surface technique...) is due to volatile molecules being formed which can dissipate into the vacuum chamber. From instance $\ce{Cl-}$ in a compound going to $\ce{Cl2}$. // Does that help?

Comment: Thanks this helps in understanding. I meant if you were to operate an SEM in EDS mode, would it be a concern that you will get an inaccurate reading of the composition of the elements in the sample, or does this generally only happen at high irradiation. I've read that you generally need to get more than 10,000 counts, so I'm wondering how much of a problem would the altering in elemental composition due to electrons bombarding the sample be at this scale.

Comment: **IT DEPENDS...**  How much an analysis might change can't be known without knowing ALL the experimental details. The gist is this. You analyze long enough to get a spectra. Say 30 seconds. You zap the specimen for 10 minutes more, then you analyze the same spot again for 30 seconds. Are the first and second spectra the same?

Comment: @AleksejusPacalovas, This paper is missing a fundamental information, what the electron beam energy? Read more and more papers and don't trust the spam and bologna of a single paper.

Comment: @M.Farooq: The paper notes " All imaging results were obtained with an accelerating voltage of 200 kV unless otherwise specified"